# Operação matemática em RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Quero saber como faço para somar determinados valores de uma RecyclerView..
no caso será o `model.getQntd()`, preciso somar todos seus respectivos resultado.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Consegui fazer a contagem o problema agora é que quando acontece agulma mudança no servidor(firebase), a soma incrementa um novo numero ao invés de modificar...
Exemplo seu eu tenho 2 valores no servidor exemplo:.

`}
 teste1:
   qntd:10
}`
...

`}
 teste2:
   qntd:10
}`

se eu mudar a `qntd` do `teste1` para `11` , o resultado será, 10+10+11=31 e não `21`, já que o `10+10` já tinha sido adicionado a lista e o `11` vem como um novo dado... se eu sair e voltar pra atividade o resultado será 21...

Agradeço desde já.

```
              mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Afiliado, BlogViewHolder>(
            Afiliado.class,
            R.layout.row_afiliados,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mQuery
    ) {

        int total =0;
        int total1 =0;

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Afiliado model, final int position) {
            final String key = getRef(position).getKey();
            final int teste = model.getQntd();

            viewHolder.mNome.setText(model.getNome());
            viewHolder.mQntd.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQntd()));
            viewHolder.mRende.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQntd()/5));
            total += teste;
            total1 += teste/5;

            mTotal1.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            mTotal2.setText(String.valueOf(total1));



            Log.i("Resultado", String.valueOf(total));

            mData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    String cod = (String) dataSnapshot.child(users).child(mUser.getUid()).child("cod").getValue();
                    for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.child(afiliados).child(cod).getChildren());
                    String resultado = dataSnapshot.child(afiliados).child(cod).getChildrenCount()+"";
                    String maxValue = (String) dataSnapshot.child(users).child(mUser.getUid()).child("maxAfiliados").getValue();

                    int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(resultado);
                    int resultado1 = valor1+total1;
                    mMeus.setText(String.valueOf(valor1));
                    mBruto.setText(String.valueOf("Resultado: "+resultado1));
                    mCircleView.setValue(resultado1);
                    mCircleView.setMaxValue(Float.parseFloat(maxValue));
                    mCod.setText(cod);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            //total+=mFireAdapter.get(position).getQntd();
            //f(position==mQuestLIst.size()-1)


        }
    };
    mFireAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mFireAdapter);

    // Update UI
    //firebaseRecycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}




public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    private TextView mNome,mQntd,mRende;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        mNome = mView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        mQntd = mView.findViewById(R.id.qntd);
        mRende = mView.findViewById(R.id.rende);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Dá uma olha nisso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089074/1377664

Comment: Como foram definidos os dados para o `RecyclerView` ? Incluir o código referente a essa parte ajuda

Comment: Então isac atualizei.

Comment: Valeu @DvD tive que mudar meu código mais deu certíssimo.

Comment: O total é um campo fixo na sua tela ou será mais uma linha (a última) dos dados exibidos?

Comment: é um campo fixo, não faz parte da recyclerview....é isso que perguntou?

Comment: este link que o DvD me passou funcionou, o problema é quando atualiza um dado no sevidor.. tipo eu tenho dois 10 no firebase se eu mudo um 10 para 11, em vez do resultado ser 21 , vira 31, o porque disso acontecer eu sei...só não sei como resolver

Comment: Seu código está mal formatado e parece que você não forneceu todo o código relevante. Por favor nos informe o código que você está utilizando para calcular o total.